# oracle - Alternative to INSTEAD OF INSERT Trigger

Tags: oracle

I want to create a trigger that prevents data insert into a table under conditions of already existing values in certain columns. However, I found out that INSTEAD OF INSERT triggers are only permitted on views and not on tables. What would be the best alternative ?

Could I create a BEFORE INSERT trigger that would allow me to cancel the subsequent INSERT under some condition ?

Answer (score 0):

There's really not enough information here to answer this question meaningfully. Generally, this sort of thing is best implemented with a constraint.

If it is an out-of-line constraint, it cannot be implemented with a `for each row` trigger, because then you'll run into a mutating table error. You can get around this by making a compound trigger, but they get more complicated.

Other things can be implemented by a materialized view with a constraint, but the mview generally has to be fast refreshable.

Answer (score 0):

There are few standard approaches to do what you want:

- Use procedures/own API for all DML changes:

  pros:

  1. most flexible: we can realize any logic, even most complex checks
  2. single point of changes

  cons:

  1. you should restrict any direct DML changes outside of your API
  2. difficullt to implement on old big systems with a lot of different apps/other integrations
- Check constraints/unique constraints
  pros:

  1. it doesn't hide logic in the code
  2. most reliable and fast(performance)

  cons:

  1. only for very simple checks
- Check/unique constraints on materialized views with `refresh fast on commit`
  pros:

  1. allows some a bit more complex checks, which can't be implemented using simple constraints on the base tables
  2. allows to aggregate/prepare your data

  cons:

  1. hides business logic
  2. not so reliable
- Simple DML triggers
  pros:

  1. easy to implement
  2. easy to find (direct dependencies)

  cons:

  1. has some limitations because of consistency requirements (aka "mutating table")
  2. generates more redo
  3. pl/sql context switches
  4. hides logic in triggers
- Compound triggers
  pros:

  1. easy to implement
  2. easy to find (direct dependencies)
  3. allows to implement most complex checks and rules

  cons:

  1. generates more redo
  2. pl/sql context switches
  3. hides logic in triggers

You can easily find more information with examples about each of them, compare them and find which one is better in your situation

Comment: Can you give a brief example of anything done through SQL that would be a substitute ? What specifically, through SQL can I define that would be different than, an "instead of insert" trigger ?

Comment: You need to provide more info about your requirements.